# win32 buttons keep flashing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, button

I made a small game in win32 c++ that works fine but i have a small problem with some buttons flashing.
I'm guessing that it has something to do with the fact that i'm sending WN_PAINT very often.

```
InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, false);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);
```

I made the buttons with CreateWindow() like this

```
CreateWindow(TEXT("button"),  TEXT(BTN_SAVE), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
            client.right - offset[1] - 170, client.bottom - offset[3], 
            80, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_BTN_SAVE, NULL, NULL);
```

Has anybody had this problem ? Is there any way i can fix it ?

Comment: You're not supposed to send `WM_PAINT` directly, instead you should invalidate the part of the window you want to be redrawn.

Comment: i'm doing this each time i need something to be updated

    InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, false);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

Comment: Then background erasure should not be a problem since you're passing `bErase` as `false` in your call to `InvalidateRect()`. Maybe your drawing routine is performing a `FillRect()` on the whole client area, or something similar?

Comment: yes i'm using FillRect() to draw the player and the obstacles in the game it looks like this http://puu.sh/2Ecsx.png
is there something wrong with using it ?

Comment: Try WS_CLIPCHILDREN style in the parent window.

Comment: Thank you Alex please make it an answer so i can choose it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style to the parent window.

`WS_CLIPCHILDREN`

Excludes the area occupied by child windows when drawing occurs within the parent window. This style is used when creating the parent window.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx